# Scala typebounds not working with abstract class but works with traits

Tags: scala, abstract-class, traits, implicit, type-bounds

I am trying to extend the generic mSort function to work with implicits and type bounds. It works fine when I use a generic trait to extend Ordered but not with an abstract class. can you please help?

```
object MergeSort extends App {

  // With Abstract Class
  abstract class Id(id: Int) extends Ordered[Id] {
    override def compare(that: Id): Int = this.id.compareTo(that.id)
  }
  case class Emp(id: Int, name: String) extends Id(id) {
    //override def compare(that: Emp): Int = this.name.compareTo(that.name)
  }

//// With Traits: Works fine
//  trait Id extends Ordered[Id]{
//    val id: Int
//    override def compare(that: Id): Int = this.id.compareTo(that.id)
//  }
//  case class Emp(id: Int, name: String) extends Id {
//    //override def compare(that: Emp): Int = this.name.compareTo(that.name)
//  }


  object MSort {
    def msort[T <% Ordered[T]](list: List[T])(implicit less: (T, T) => Boolean): List[T] = {
      def merge(xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): List[T] = {
    (xs, ys) match {
      case (Nil, _) => ys
      case (_, Nil) => xs
      case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) => if (less(x, y)) x :: merge(xs1, ys) else y :: merge(xs, ys1)
    }
      }
      val n = list.length/2
      if(n==0) list
      else {
    val (ys, zs) = list.splitAt(n)
    merge(msort(ys), msort(zs))
      }
    }
  }

  implicit def less [T <% Ordered[T]] (x: T, y: T): Boolean = x <= y
//  MSort.msort[Int](List(6, 3, 9, 1)).foreach(println)
//  MSort.msort[Char](List('a', 'z', 'Z', 'D')).foreach(println)
//  MSort.msort[String](List("appolo", "lunar", "Zapplin", "Kafka")).foreach(println)
//  MSort.msort[Double](List(12.3, 14, 19.3, -32.443)).foreach(println)
  MSort.msort[Id](List(Emp(7, "appolo"), Emp(2, "lunar"), Emp(9, "Zapplin"), Emp(1, "Kafka"))).foreach(println)

}
```

Error:

```
Error:(5, 66) value id is not a member of MergeSort.Id
override def compare(that: Id): Int = this.id.compareTo(that.id)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the "val" id is just a constructor arg, not a property of the class.

```
abstract class Id(id: Int) extends Ordered[Id] {
  override def compare(that: Id): Int = this.id.compareTo(that.id)
}
```

That also means that your id argument in Emp needs to be flagged as an override

```
case class Emp(override val id: Int, name: String) extends Id(id) {
  //override def compare(that: Emp): Int = this.name.compareTo(that.name)
}
```